# Is there a setting to suppress C-Style comments appearing as DOC in Oracle Output?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Just again looking at some log from an oracle script, where the developer intended to comment out some part not to add documentation.

I don't want that a script containing code like this

```
/*
select getWochentag(SYSDATE) from DUAL;
select
    getWochentag (SYSDATE    ) || isWeekend (SYSDATE    ), 
    getWochentag (SYSDATE + 1) || isWeekend (SYSDATE + 1), 
    getWochentag (SYSDATE + 2) || isWeekend (SYSDATE + 2), 
    getWochentag (SYSDATE + 3) || isWeekend (SYSDATE + 3), 
    getWochentag (SYSDATE + 4) || isWeekend (SYSDATE + 4), 
    getWochentag (SYSDATE + 5) || isWeekend (SYSDATE + 5), 
    getWochentag (SYSDATE + 6) || isWeekend (SYSDATE + 6)
FROM DUAL;

*/
```

produces output like

```
DOC>select getWochentag(SYSDATE) from DUAL;
DOC>select
DOC>        getWochentag (SYSDATE    ) || isWeekend (SYSDATE    ),
DOC>        getWochentag (SYSDATE + 1) || isWeekend (SYSDATE + 1),
DOC>        getWochentag (SYSDATE + 2) || isWeekend (SYSDATE + 2),
DOC>        getWochentag (SYSDATE + 3) || isWeekend (SYSDATE + 3),
DOC>        getWochentag (SYSDATE + 4) || isWeekend (SYSDATE + 4),
DOC>        getWochentag (SYSDATE + 5) || isWeekend (SYSDATE + 5),
DOC>        getWochentag (SYSDATE + 6) || isWeekend (SYSDATE + 6)
DOC>FROM DUAL;
DOC>
DOC>*/
```

I just want to see nothing in the log. (Only empty logs are good logs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SET DOC[UMENT] OFF`

At least in 9i. I can't make these comments display at all in 10g, so I think they've made this option even more obsolete - it still controls explicit `DOC` blocks, but apparently not comment blocks...

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to suppress comments from login.sql

While using "--" style comments are not displayed, rem and /* */ are displayed!

Environment: Using SQL*Plus: Release 9.0.1.3.0